# masstransit publisher / consumer in the same application

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are testing MassTransit, and we were wondering if a same service could have two or more consumers that each publish/consumes the messages between others.

```
           var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "CropMetricsIngestExternal_RequestDevicesPerUser", e =>
                e.Consumer<RequestDevicePerUserConsumer>());

            x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "CropMetricsIngestExternal_RequestDataPerDevice", e =>
                e.Consumer<RequestDataPerDeviceConsumer>());
        });
```

In this case in this consumer we have the RequestDevicePerUserConsumer that gets all devices and then publishes a message to CropMetricsIngestExternal_RequestDataPerDevice that the consumer RequestDataPerDeviceConsumer processes.

We are wondering if this would be fit for a production scenario. Since MassTransit does create an instance per message received, looks like it would be the same to have them in separated projects or just in separated classes.

Comment: I see no problem with this code, is there anything that doesn't work as you expect it to work?

Comment: No actually is more that it "feels" wrong to me having both the consumer and the producer in the same application. Mostly because if the resources are handled in the same way.

Comment: Also we are wondering what's the actual memory/cpu cost on creating the bus.

Comment: You aren't creating the bus multiple times, you create two separate receive endpoints for the same bus. There's no overhead except you will have two queues in RMQ. I don't see any issue with that.

Comment: Absolutely fit for production, simplifies deployment, etc, etc. Also keeps broker resource usage down since a single connection is established for multiple receive endpoints. Go for it!